# launchSettings.json launchUrl doesn't work "api/values"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.2

I am trying to change http://localhost:5001/api/values route but the program is stuck this url.

I read this solutions

[How to change the default controller and action in ASP.NET Core API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233964/how-to-change-the-default-controller-and-action-in-asp-net-core-api)

[How to redirect root to swagger in Asp.Net Core 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290683/how-to-redirect-root-to-swagger-in-asp-net-core-2-x)

https://medium.com/quick-code/routing-in-asp-net-core-c433bff3f1a4

Everyone write same thing but not work for me.

My `launchSetting.json` file is

```
{  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54650",
      "sslPort": 44382
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ShoppingBasketAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to change `app.UseMvc();`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2

this is also not working.Where does `api/values` come from? I can't figure out .

My controller attribute route is 
`[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`

Answer (score 7):

When you create new ASP.Net Core Web API project you will see that in project property there is `launchUrl` setting that set to `"api/values"` path. So you can change it to what ever url you want or you can change in your launchSetting.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54356",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication4": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So you will see in profiles section there will be 2 config. One is for IIS express (when using Visual Studio to run your code) and WebApplication4 (when you run project using dotnet run) so you can change into

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54356",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication4": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So when you use VS to run the project or `dotnet run` command is will always serve the swagger url first.

Comment: Yes but this isn't work both of them . I stil get api/values route.Can it be because I use macOS?

Comment: @HaktanEnesBiçer I dont think so . Try to search api/values in the project to see if there any code left contain that ? My approach work perfectly fine. I think there is something wrong in the code

Comment: I found the problem. It is because of visual studio mac.I searched before 'api/values' it can't find any code.

Comment: Wow, almost everything you wrote is wrong. There is no Launch browser setting, it's launchBrowser and the OP has the right value, VSC is not honoring it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using VSCode and is happening the same to me, but on Windows.
I am just enhancing a bit the answer here.

I have tried VS2019 and it worked in that IDE, so it is supposely to do with VSCode.
I have searched for other answers and I found this.

> [vscode launch.json debug and open specific url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900193/vscode-launch-json-debug-and-open-specific-url)

What fixed my issue was to go to .vscode/launch.json file and append:

```
         "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": true,
            "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd.exe",
                "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}/swagger"
            }
```

as Anton Dremin describes, just add the above into the configurations section.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of Visual Studio for Mac. I was able to get the correct url to chance `Run With>Custom Configuration > Run Action --> Debug .Net Core Debugger`